# gcc auto link shared libraries needed by static libraries

Tags: gcc, premake, nana

I've installed the `Nana` library and I've read from their website that the library needs some shared libraries to work.. So during linking (gcc) i need to put all links (-lXft, -l...).
Is there a solution to auto link shared libraries needed by Nana?

I am using ubuntu 18.04 and I've read that I can do that with `Makefile` but I haven't understood how.. I want to use `Premake` to organize my project so that I can say to Premake that it needs to include the Nana library and then Premake "smartly" find all shared libraries..

When I used Premake and I linked the Nana library (statically) the compiler gaves me a lot of errors...
all the errors say:

> undefined reference to: X...

So I need to include all the shared libraries that Nana needs, but how?

Comment: Look up *pkgconfig* system, it is for getting compiler and linker options for using libraries which need other libraries etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gcc has no idea about inter-library dependencies. You need a build system (which would use gcc as the compiler) for that.

Now, the Nana library [uses](https://github.com/cnjinhao/nana/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) the CMake build system. Thus a good solution to the problem should be to get the authors of Nana to properly [export](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/chapters/install/exporting.html) the library's CMake targets, and distribute a `.cmake` file which you can then import if you also build with CMake.

Alternatively - perhaps such a CMake file already exists somewhere (I haven't been able to quickly find it though).

I would ask about this in the [Nana forums](http://nanapro.org/en-us/forum/).

Comment: Thanks, I changed my mind, for now I am specifing the dynamics library in Premake and I'm doing fine

Comment: I prefer to recommend to [add_subdirectory(nana ..)](https://github.com/qPCR4vir/nana-demo/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L24) and then [target_link_libraries(my_project PUBLIC nana)](https://github.com/qPCR4vir/nana-demo/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L32). What do you think?

Comment: @qPCR4vir: That's not the proper way to do it. Nana is a separate, independent project - not a subdirectory of your own.

Comment: but compiling separately led to lot of hard to fix errors if flags/options are not compatible. What will be a proper way to do a nana compilation withing your project build? Lots of errors come from people first installing compiled nana an then consuming that without recompilation when flags changed.

Comment: @qPCR4vir: I don't have a really good answer to give you. However, a repository needs to export all of its relevant settings via a .cmake file, so that dependent repositories can then apply their own logic - e.g. whether flags are compatible. In the general case, you may have a large hierarchy of dependent libraries - you can't just make them all subfolders of your application's source tree.

Comment: I never put nana or other dependencies in a subdirectory of my application's tree. I find unfortunate we have `add_subdirectory` instead of `add_directory`. I will continue to investigate.